# Sqlite no longer opens Google Drive database

Tags: c++, sqlite

The path to the Google Drive folder can be found in the file **`...\AppData\Local\Google\Drive\sync_config.db`**, which is an SQLITE3 database. My Windows C++ program used to get this data successfully, but recently it stopped working, both on my PC and for customers that I've heard from. The database must still be valid, because I can use the **`sqlite3`** command-line utility to open the database and successfully query it with the exact query that I'm trying to use programatically.

What happens in the code as shown below is that it never gets past `**sqlite3_prepare_v2**`, which returns error code **`26`**. This code generally indicates that the file is not a valid database. So why does the command-line utility work?

Any ideas what could have changed that would suddenly break this code?

```
extern CString GoogleDrivePath()
{
  CString sPath = "";
  CString sDbPath;
  char acValue[1024];
  DWORD lSize = sizeof(acValue);
  struct _stat fstat;
  sqlite3 *pDb;
  sqlite3_stmt *pStmt;
  int iSts;
  char acSelect[] = "SELECT data_value FROM data WHERE entry_key = 'local_sync_root_path';";
  const unsigned char *pPath;

  DWORD lLen = GetEnvironmentVariable("LOCALAPPDATA", acValue, lSize);
  if (lSize <= 0) return(sPath);

  sDbPath = acValue;
  sDbPath += "\\Google\\Drive\\sync_config.db";
  if (_stat(sDbPath, &fstat) < 0) return(sPath);

  iSts = sqlite3_open_v2(sDbPath, &pDb, SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY, NULL);
  if (iSts) return(sPath);
  iSts = sqlite3_prepare_v2(pDb, acSelect, -1, &pStmt, NULL);
  if (!iSts)  {
    iSts = sqlite3_step(pStmt);
    if (iSts == SQLITE_ROW) {
      pPath = sqlite3_column_text(pStmt, 0);
      if (pPath != NULL)  {
        sPath = pPath;
      }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(pStmt);
  }

  sqlite3_close(pDb);
  return(sPath);
}
```

Comment: Wild guess from random googling: it seems like SQLite likes to return `SQLITE_NOTADB` even in unrelated circumstances, like when the query syntax is wrong. The only thing that seems off in yours is the trailing `;` in the SQL string, which is probably unnecessary. Could you try the program without it?

Comment: No, that wasn't it. The mystery is that this used to work as-is, but now fails. That implies to me that Google changed something within the database that is not agreeing with my configuration or build of SQLite. It's not strictly a version thing either, as the command-line utility is also V3.6.23, and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix. My product was built with V3.6 and stopped working; the command-line utility that worked was actually V3.7. So I rebuilt the program with sqlite3.c V3.7.14.1 and it now works!

So apparently Google uses a newer version of SQLite that somehow makes the database not backward-compatible.

(Since my program also creates a SQLite database that is then used on Android devices, I was a bit concerned about updating my version, but it appears to be working OK.)

Answer (score 0):

The command-line utility does not try to open the database in read-only mode.
Try `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE`.

There are two reasons why read-only mode might fail: the database has a hot journal and needs recovery, or you have enabled WAL.

Comment: Not it. See my comment above. It used to work, so something about that database must have changed.

Comment: I've listed two reasons that are something about the database that might have changed. Just try without READONLY.